# Error when using .classList.add

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm playing around with `.classList` and I'm getting some odd errors in my console. [**Here's my demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/ND6EH/)

Basically, I have an array of images all with the class of child and I'm doing a javascrpt `.querySelectorAll` to store those images in a variable for further manipulation.

```
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.child');

console.log(el.classList;);
el.classList.add("someClass");
```

But when I open up my console I'm getting some errors .

This one in reference to `.classList;`
    undefined 
And this one in reference to `.classList.add();`

```
 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined
```

Yet, when I switch to looking up elements by ID, the errors go away. Now using IDs isn't out of the question, but ideally I'd like to keep things to class Names. Any idea what's going on?

Comment: `querySelectorAll`, as the name implies, returns a collection of elements. The collection doesn't have a `classList` property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el is a collection, not a single DOM element. classList does not make much sense for an array, though. So what you might want to do:

```
var product = document.getElementsByClassName('product');
var el = document.querySelectorAll('.child');
for(var i = 0; i < el.length; i++) {
    el[i].classList.add("someClass");
    console.log(el[i].classList);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This actually is more of what I need to do.